# Quotient space of the solid cube via identification of faces

Tags: general-topology

Consider the quotient space of a cube $I^3$, where $I=[-1,1]$, obtained by the following identification.
$$
(1,y,z)\sim (−1,y,z),\quad (x,1, z)\sim (−x,−1,z)\quad \text{and} \quad (x,y,1)\sim(x,y,−1).
$$
how to describe the quotient space $X \!/\!_{\sim}$ as a product space?

[image: Solide cube]

So we identify the cube ABFE with the cube DCGH, identify the cube BFGC with the cube DAEH and twist the cube ABCD with the cube EFGH.

it is not possible to draw such pictures as Escher's illustration

[image: Escher’s illustration]

I'm confused about following the process of how such an object is made.

Any help is warmly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know its 2d analogue? That's the torus.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $K$ be a spce obtianed as $I^2/R$ where R is as follows:  $(-1,y)\sim (1,y), (x,1)\sim (-x,-1)$.

This space is just Klein bottle. (See diagram with squares in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle)

2. Now your space is just $K\times S^1$ where $S^1$ is a circle.(In the first two equations $z$ remains unchanged). It follows from the following general fact:

Let $Y$ be some space and $T=(Y\times I)/R'$ where $R'$ is $(t,1)\sim (t,-1)$. Then $Y\cong Y\times S^1$

Comment: Please can you provide more information on the following topics?  Escher's illustration